# C# webforms ajax reload next 15 items

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that consist of product comments with some information about them. Only 15 comments are shown. I have all comments saved in cache and with the page load I am loading them to `public List<NewCommentsItem> NewCommentsList { get; set; }` property. The generation of the page goes like this:

```
<div class="product-list product-list-comments">
    <ul class="reset">

        <% for (int i = (PageNum-1) * 15; i < PageNum * 15; i++)
           { %>

            <% if (i < NewCommentsList.Count) 
                {   %>

                <li class="item">
                    <div class="spc">                      
                      <%= NewCommentsList[i].Data %>
                    </div>
                </li>
        <%      }
           } %>

    </ul>
</div>
```

In the aspx.cs file everything is done in `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method.

I need to be able to load next 15 products using ajax, but I don't know how to handle the communication. Whether and how should I use `Page.Response` method or something else I don't know.

Comment: I don't know how to give the data from the application to the javascript part.

Comment: Make WebMethods on your server side then by one ajax call you will be able to do this all